# Having trouble replacing an input in Prompt dialog box to asterisks

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to replace the input of my prompt dialog box with asterisks. For example I write tom then i want the alert dialog box to display your password is ***.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//declared variables
var input1 =0;
var dis = input1.length;


input1=prompt("Please enter your Password here","Enter Password Here");
dis.replace(/./gmi, '*')
window.alert("Valid password "+ input1 + "\n You entered the password " + 
input1);
</script>
```

I tried this but it said replace is undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide the password entered via a Javascript dialog prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554987/how-can-i-hide-the-password-entered-via-a-javascript-dialog-prompt)

Comment: I didn't get any help from that. I need it to be Javascript not html.

Comment: Why use JS when you can designate the textbox type as password and the entry will be displayed as asteriks.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your current question to ask a new one. To ask another question, you should make a new question using the Ask Question button. BTW, make sure your new question is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first, your edited in question definitely would not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could get creative here (it's meant as an alternative to using `replace()`)

```
var plainText = prompt("Please enter your Password here", "Enter Password Here");
var asterisks = (new Array(plainText.length+1).join("*"));

// if you enter "Tom" you get
//
// plainText = "Tom"
// asterisks = "***"
```

Answer (score 2):

if i properly understand, then you should not use `replace(" ", "*")` as [replace() replaces only first character](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

use Regular Expressions for that (overload for replace() method). This will look like `input1.replace(/./gmi, '*')`

Comment: It's not working because I need to display the results in an alert dialog box

Answer (score -3):

You simply make the entry field like this:

Comment: "<asp:TextBox id="tb2" TextMode="password" runat="server" /> "

Comment: it's a java-script question