# How can I hide the password entered by a user in a dialog prompt in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I hide the password entered by a user in a dialog prompt in JavaScript?
I have a prompt that I wrote in JavaScript. When a user types his password, it should shows as ****.

```
 function ConfirmIt()
        {
           var x = prompt('Enter your PassWord ');
                var control = '<%=HiddenField2.ClientID%>';
                if (x !== "") {
               document.getElementById(control).value = x;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(control).value = "0";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Switch to a modal and use `<input type=password>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide the password entered via a JavaScript dialog prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554987/how-can-i-hide-the-password-entered-via-a-javascript-dialog-prompt)

Comment: I go through that link...but it'z not working