# How can I hide the password entered in a JavaScript dialog prompt with asterisk characters?

Tags: javascript, passwords, prompt

How can I hide the password entered by a user in a dialog prompt in JavaScript? For example, using something like this:

```
function ConfirmIt()
{
    var control4 = '<%=HiddenDelete.ClientID%>';
    if (document.getElementById(control4).value == "True")
    {
        var x = prompt('Enter your Password ')
        var control = '<%=HiddenField2.ClientID%>';
        if (x !== "") {
            document.getElementById(control).value = x;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(control).value = "0";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No Permission");
    }
}
```

I would like that when e.g. `12345` is entered it appears like `*****` or `.....` in the dialogue box. After that I want to select the password in a hiddenfield. Can anyone suggest how I can do this or provide some example code?

Comment: just make the type as password,<input type="password" name="pwd">

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types)

Comment: can u plz were i declare?

Comment: can we see your html ?

Comment: He asking about javascript prompt feature.

Comment: Then it's not possible. Unless you write your completely custom prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide the password entered via a JavaScript dialog prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554987/how-can-i-hide-the-password-entered-via-a-javascript-dialog-prompt)

Comment: @vlaz can u plz help me

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i want it in asp.net

Comment: @Lima Is that password textbox resides inside `prompt()` dialog? If yes, read the dupe link. If not, you can create `asp:TextBox` control and set `TextMode="Password"`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto just to add - the dupe link mentions setting a BasicAuthentication header in PHP. If OP *really* wants to use that option, then there would also be a way to add that header in ASP.NET. Although, I don't think it's a good approach because I don't think OP really wants to collect a password in a "prompt". In short, I think you're right and this question seems a lot like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

Simple option is make the filed as password type

```
<input type="password" name="pwd">
```

It is better and easy to use Jquery Popup window or Dialog box if you are looking for a popup type window 
which will support with the password fields.

If you really want to stick into prompt then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554987/how-can-i-hide-the-password-entered-via-a-javascript-dialog-prompt)

Comment: i want to display it is on prompt box

Comment: using javascript

Comment: if you want to stick into javascript only then have to create a custom prompt

Comment: i am using this javascript to display prompt..in this password is not asterisk..          
                var x = prompt('Enter your Password ')

Comment: why do you want to stick with prompt ? popups you can show what ever html you want. So crate a HTML page with a password textbox, show it in the popup, get the value simple procedure right ?

Comment: @Lima: It can't be done with the Window.prompt function. Please take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554987/how-can-i-hide-the-password-entered-via-a-javascript-dialog-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the prompt() method is use to collect text input value. you can't use for collect an password information. Of-course, there are multiple similar ways you can achieve your goal. you can use jQuery modal popup at [link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

But as you mentioned, it should be appear like ***** in browser dialogue. So you need to use an ASP.NET/HTML feature.

```
<input type="password" id="myPwd" name="myPwd">
```

OR

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```